# Canceled event is not reverting RadTextBox to initial value

Tags: javascript, telerik, closures, invocation, radtextbox

Recently, I have refactored my javascript to better utilize closures and invocation.

### The Problem

Setting the `cancel` property (to `true`) of the telerik eventArgument (`e`) accompanying the RadButton Client **OnValueChanging** event is **no longer** setting the value back to the **oldValue** or **initialValue**.

### Paysheet.UI

```
window.Paysheet.UI.WorkRate = { 
    "OnValueChanging"   : function (sender, e, args) {
        /// <summary>Entry-Point Function; initializes and calls 'Paysheet.XHR.POST', evaluates the response; Initializes and invokes the proper RadWindow/RadAlert/RadPrompt</summary>
        /// <param name="sender" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadTextBox">The Telerik Control that raises the event</param>
        /// <param name="e" type="Telerik.Web.UI.InputValueChangingEventArgs">The Telerik Event</param>
        /// <param name="args" type="JSON">JSON that is to be processed by the handler, and posted</param>

        args = Paysheet.Common.GetDataKeyValues(sender);
        args.RequestorID = window.Paysheet.Requestor.ID;
        //args.AuthToken = window.Paysheet.Requestor.AuthToken;

        args.Scope = "PaysheetItem";
        args.PaysheetItemScope = "PayRate";
        args.RateType = "WorkRate";
        args.Rate = e.get_newValue();
        args._uri = "Paysheet/" + args.PayPeriodEmployeeID + "/PayRate/Modify";

        console.log("(1st) XHR POST => args: %o", args);
        return Paysheet.Common.Func(Paysheet.Common.OnValueChangingResultHandler, sender, e, args);
    }
};
```

The above code is called from the **RadTextBox** OnValueChanging EventHandler like so:

```
"valueChanging": function(sender, e) {
    args = {};
    console.log(" [EventOccurring] - sender: %o - e: %o - args: %o", sender, e, args); 
    e._cancel = !(Paysheet.UI.WorkRate.OnValueChanging(sender, e, args));
}
```

### Paysheet.XHR

```
 window.Paysheet.XHR = {
    "POST": function (uri, jsonData) {
        /// <summary>Encapsulates the XmlHttpRequest object; posts the given data (JSON string) to a specified handler page and returns the JSON object</summary>
        /// <param name="url" type="String">URI</param>
        /// <param name="jsonData" type="String">JSON Data to be posted</param>

        uri = uri || jsonData._uri;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", uri, false); // synchronous call
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        return (xhr.status == 200) ? JSON.parse(xhr.response) : { "isValid": false, "StatusCode": 500 };
    }
};
```

### Paysheet.Common

```
window.Paysheet.Common = {
    "Func": function (func, sender, e, args) {
        console.log("Call to func..");
        var result = func(sender, e, args, (Paysheet.XHR.POST(args._uri, args) || { "isValid": false, "isOverrideable" : false, "StatusCode": 500 }));
        console.log("result of call: %o", result);
        return result;
    },
    "GenericResultHandler": function (result, handlers) {
        result = result || { "isValid": false, "isOverrideable": false, "StatusCode": 500 };

        if (result.StatusCode != 200) {
            console.log("[ERROR] - [RadAlert] Invoked...");
            //the result.message show be more domain specific.
            radalert(result.message || "Internal Error Occurred!", 400, 350, result.title || "Alert - Error", null, null);

        } else if (result.isValid) {

            console.log("[APPROVED]");
            handlers.approve();

            return true;
        } else if (result.isOverrideable) {

            console.log("[OVERRIDE] - [RadPrompt] Invoked...");
            handlers.override();
        } else {

            console.log("[REJECTED] - [RadAlert] Invoked...");
            handlers.reject();

            //the result.message show be more domain specific.
            radalert(result.message || "The state of this data prevents any modifications; Overriding is not an option.",
                400, 350,
                result.title || "Alert - Denied",
                null, null);
        }

        // ultimately, the caller will be a cancelable telerik event.
        //    by convension, the result is inverted/flipped: thus, this resolves to 'e.set_cancel = !([return])'
        //    note: override will have to set the value explicitly without triggering this event in the (presumed) asynchronous method call to 'handlers.override';
        return false;
    },
    "GenericOverrideResultHandler": function (result, handlers) {
        result = result || { "isValid": false, "StatusCode": 500, "isOverrideable" : false };            

        if (result.StatusCode != 200) {
            console.log("[OVERRIDE ERROR] - [RadAlert] Invoked...");
            radalert(result.message || "Internal Error Occurred!", 400, 350, result.title || "Alert - Error", null, null);
        } else if (result.isValid) {
            console.log("[OVERRIDE APPROVED]");
            handlers.approve();
        } else {
            console.log("[OVERRIDE REJECTED] - [RadAlert] Invoked...");

            //the result.message show be more domain specific.
            radalert(result.message || "Override was denied, no modification made to stored data!", 400, 350, result.title || "Alert - Override Denied", null, null);
            handlers.reject();
        }
    },
    "OnValueChangingResultHandler": function (sender, e, args, result) {
        return Paysheet.Common.GenericResultHandler(result, { "approve": approve, "override": override, "reject": reject });

        function approve() {
            var d = Paysheet.Common.GetDataKeyValues(sender);
            var DaysCell = sender.get_parent().get_cell("Days");
            if (DaysCell["set_value"]) {
                DaysCell.set_value(result.content.Days);
            } else {
                DaysCell.innerHTML = result.content.Days;
            }

            var GrossCell = sender.get_parent().get_cell("Gross");
            if (GrossCell["set_value"]) {
                GrossCell.set_value(result.content.Gross);
            } else {
                GrossCell.innerHTML = result.content.Gross;
            }
        }

        function override() {
            radprompt(result.message, callback, 400, 350, null, result.title || "Prompt - Override", false);

            function callback(promptArgs) {
                promptArgs = promptArgs || { "override": false, "note": "" };

                if (promptArgs.override && promptArgs.note.length > 0) {
                    args.Override = promptArgs.override;
                    args.OverrideNote = promptArgs.note;
                    console.log("(2nd) XHR POST [start] => args: %o", args);
                    var result = Paysheet.XHR.POST(args._uri, args);
                    console.log("(2nd) XHR POST [finished] - results: %o", result);
                    if ((result) ? result.isValid : false) {
                        console.log("[SUCCESS]");
                        sender._setNewValue(e.get_newValue());
                        var d = Paysheet.Common.GetDataKeyValues(sender);
                        //Update Gross;
                        var DaysCell = sender.get_parent().get_cell("Days");
                        if (DaysCell["set_value"]) {
                            DaysCell.set_value(result.content.Days);
                        } else {
                            DaysCell.innerHTML = result.content.Days;
                        }

                        var GrossCell = sender.get_parent().get_cell("Gross");
                        if (GrossCell["set_value"]) {
                            GrossCell.set_value(result.content.Gross);
                        } else {
                            GrossCell.innerHTML = result.content.Gross;
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("[FAILED]");
                        sender._SetValue(sender._initialValueAsText);
                        sender.updateDisplayValue();
                        if (result.StatusCode == 200) {
                            console.log("... Denied [RadAlert] Invoked...");
                            radalert(result.message || "Override request denied!", 400, 350, result.title || "Alert - Override Denied", null, null);
                        } else //if (result.StatusCode == 500)
                        {
                            console.log("... Error [RadAlert] Invoked...");
                            radalert(result.message || "Internal Error Occurred!", 400, 350, result.title || "Alert - Error", null, null);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // ensuring the control retains the same value; for the prompt is async;
                    sender._SetValue(e.get_oldValue());
                    sender.updateDisplayValue();
                }
            }
        }

        function reject() {
            // neither of the following lines should be necessary, for the GenericResultHandler returns true|false to `e._cancel`
            // sender._SetValue(e.get_oldValue()); //This line works
            // e._cancel = true; //This line does not work
        }
    }
};
```

---

I've stepped through this code, and into the telerik's code. It does seem to call `_SetValue` using the `_initialValueAsText`. I just doesn't seem to actually apply.

If I explicitly set the cancel property of the event in my 'reject' function. It exhibits the same issue.

If I explicitly set the value of the sender to the old value, it works.

---

**EDIT**: I have commented out `xhr.send` line (synchronous call) - forcing the `POST` function to return `{ "isValid" : false, "isOverrideable" : false, "StatusCode": 500 }` - the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `sender._setHiddenValue(e.get_newValue())` at some point prior to assigning `true` or `false` to the `event._canceled` corrects the issue..

---

`_setHiddenValue(value)` conditionally sets the `_text` and `_value` fields of the `sender` to the new value: it checks the passed `value` against the existing `_value`, if they are the same, then the function exits without assigning the value. It exits with a `true` or `false` value indicating whether the assignment occurred.

If/when the `_canceled` field of the **eventArg** is set to `true`, the internal event handler calls `sender._SetValue(sender._initialValueAsText)`; Within that procedure, `sender._setHiddenValue(sender._initialValueAsText)` is called.

Comment: the Telerik team is investigating this as a control bug: http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/152532-fix-set-cancel-method-of-the-args-in-radtextbox-onvaluechanging-event-is-taking-e